# EmberJS: Observer Not Being Triggered on Computed Property

Tags: forms, ember.js

I am building a handelbars helper that renders a checkbox group.  My goal is to display a checkbox group with something like this and get two-way binding on `selectedOptions`:

```
{{form-checkboxGroup options=allOptions selectedOptions=selectedOptions}}
```

I've used this pattern successfully with other form components and it's a big win.  I'm able to render my `allOptions` and `selectedOptions` values as a checkbox group, but it's the two-way binding that's tripping me up.  Any idea what I'm missing?

By the way, I'm using `ember-cli`, but that doesn't affect anything relating to this issue.

Here's my setup:

**Handlebars Helper: helpers/form-checkbox-group.js**

The sole purpose of this file is to link the Handelbars expression `{{form-checkboxGroup}}` to the view and template below.

```
import FormCheckboxGroupView from 'my-app/views/util/form/form-checkbox-group';

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function( options ) {
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, FormCheckboxGroupView, options);
});
```

**CheckboxGroup Handlebars Template: templates/util/form/form-checkbox-group.hbs**

```
...
{{#each user in view.combinedOptions}}
    {{input type="checkbox" name="view.fieldName" checked=user.checked }} {{user.name}}
{{/each}}
...
```

**CheckboxGroup View: views/util/form/form-checkbox-group.js**

```
...
export default FormCheckboxGroupView = Ember.View.extend( FormFieldMixin, {
    templateName: 'util/form/form-checkbox-group',

    selectedOptions: function() {
        console.log("When triggered this could update view.selectedOptions");
    }.observes('view.combinedOptions.@each.checked'),

    // combines the "options" and "selected options" into a single array of "combinedOptions" explicitly indicating what's checked
    combinedOptions: function() {
        ...
        // sample result of combinedOptions:
        // { name: "Johnny Five", id: "12", checked: true }
        return combinedOptions;
    }.property('view.options', 'view.selectedOptions')
});
```

And finally, to actually use my Handlebars helper, here's the consuming page's template and corresponding controller:

**Consuming Page: templates/my-page.hbs**

```
{{form-checkboxGroup options=allUsersArray selectedOptions=selectedUsersArray fieldName="selectedProvidersArray" }}
```

**Backing Controller for Consuming Page: controllers/my-page.js**

```
export default MyPageController = Ember.Controller.extend( FormMixin, {

    allUsersArray: [
        { name: 'Bill Huxtable',     id: 'billy' },
        { name: 'Samantha Jones',    id: 'jones' },
        { name: 'Tony Pepperoni',    id: 'tonyp' },
        { name: 'Ridonk Youliss',    id: 'silly' }
    ],

    selectedUsersArray: [
        { name: 'Tony Pepperoni',    id: 'tonyp' },
        { name: 'Ridonk Youliss',    id: 'silly' }
    ],

    ...
});
```

So, all of this successfully renders the checkbox group nicely, but my efforts to capture the fact that a checkbox has been newly selected by using `observes("view.combinedOptions.@each.checked')` is not working.

Any idea on how I can this up for two-way binding?  Thanks in advance for assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No jsbin so I'm flying blind, but try this:

```
selectedOptions: function() {
    console.log("When triggered this could update view.selectedOptions");
}.observes('combinedOptions.@each.checked')
```

`view.property` is how you access view from template. You don't need that from the view itself (unless you have `view` property on your view).

Comment: That actually worked! I could have sworn I tried all combinations of `view.x` and `x` directly, but as soon as I took out view it worked.  I did have to also change the method name from `selectedOptions` to something other than `selectedOptions`, which makes sense since `selectedOptions` is a bound var, whereas the function in your response is an observer only.  Thanks!

Comment: Re: JsBin, I feel like they never successfully output when I see others use them, but I agree it's a great practice.  Will do next time.  Thanks again.